# How can I test that ConcurrentHashMap is truly thread-safe?

Tags: java, concurrency, hashtable

Just learning more about threads and concurrency, and thought of playing around with a regular hashtable and a ConcurrentHashMap.

What would be a good way to test for concurrency for these hashtables?

(obviously the hash table will fail this test)

It would be cool if I could also somehow keep track of how many reads/writes the test performs to see which one (ht or conccurrent ht) faster.

Comment: I can tell you that the basic hashtable will be faster, but the cost is obviously that threads could clobber the data and make the whole thing inconsistent...

Comment: You can never test for safety -- you can only prove that it doesn't exist.

Comment: You got it wrong about Hashtable: it is thread-safe.  It is however deprecated and has been replaced by HashMap, which is not thread-safe.

Comment: so how could I write code to test these conditions, and use a similar non-thread safe data structure (the thread-safe concurrent counterpart)  to play around with this?

Comment: Start two threads, one increments the integer value for a specified test key in the map and the other reads it. Or try inserting incremented keys and observe what order the other thread sees them appear. It won't be a proper test  (as such tests are impossible to write) but it might demonstrate what could happen.

Comment: Well, I did run into an issue once where ConcurrentHashMap throws a ConcurrentModificationException: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=1482514&group_id=93852&atid=605791.  That was a while back, but it's possible you might find something.  I was never able to create a test to force it to fail, it would only happen in a live run.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an answer to your last edit about how you can test it.  This also touches on Hot Licks comment.  In practice you can't really test thread safety as it is highly non-deterministic and failures usually occur over long periods of time.

There is a [nice race condition](http://mailinator.blogspot.com/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html) with a non-thread-safe HashMap.  Which `put`ing into the HashMap with multiple threads can cause it to go into an infinite loop.  Run code similar to this

```
    ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    public void test(final Map<Object,Object> map){
       for(int i =0; i < 5000; i++){
           e.submit(new Runnable(){
               public void run(){
                    map.put(new Object(),new Object());
               } 
           });
       }
    }

test(new HashMap<Object,Object>()); //will probably go into an infinite loop
test(new ConcurrentHashMap<Object,Object>()); //will *never* go into an infinite loop
```

Note I used probably because you can run this test a number of times and not go into an infinite loop, but I have done this test and can easily get the loop to occur

Comment: It is indeed a beautiful race condition

Comment: minor suggestion: your function and argument have the same name (`test`)