# Scala: How to test the concurrency of a mutable.Set

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, set, concurrenthashmap

In Scala, both concurrent and non-concurrent Sets have exactly the same type:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._

// A regular Set in Scala, not concurrent.
val regularSet: mutable.Set[Int] = mutable.Set[Int]()

// A concurrent set. It has the same type as a regular set, but underneath, it is actually concurrent. In my opinion, this is a flaw in the type system for Scala collections
val concurrentSet: mutable.Set[Int] = java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet[Int]().asScala
```

I'd like a way to actually test whether a set is concurrent or not.

Comment: please add either the required imports or the required version (is it deprecated) as `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet[Int]().asScala` does not compile. `asScala` is unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

You can test it empirically by creating a lot of threads which are trying to add/remove the same elements from a shared `mutable.Set`

```
import java.util.concurrent.{Callable, ExecutorService, Executors}
import scala.collection.mutable

def testSet(set: mutable.Set[Int]) {
  val e: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)
  val tasks = for (i <- 0 to 50000) yield {
    e.submit(new Callable[Unit]() {
      override def call() {
        for (j <- 0 to 10) {
          set.add(i + j)

          // This will throw a Null Pointer Exception for the non-concurrent version
          // This is because it is trying to remove something that another thread already removed.
          set.remove(i + j) 
        }
      }
    })
  }
  for (result <- tasks) result.get()
  e.shutdown()
}

// Can't check the type! They have the same type.
val regularSet: mutable.Set[Int] = mutable.Set[Int]()
val concurrentSet: mutable.Set[Int] = java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet[Int]().asScala

testSet(concurrentSet) // Success!
testSet(regularSet) // FAILS! Almost always throws a NullPointerException on my system.
```

**Limitations**

Running the test will require system resources such as threads and CPU time. It is not really appropriate to run this in production at runtime.

This is not a *deductive proof*. There is a tiny chance that the test will classify a non-concurrent object as being concurrent, since the race condition is random. However, running the test for longer will cause the probability of detecting non-concurrent objects to approach certainty.

**Additional Comments**

Ideally there would be a way to use reflection and the type system to see what the underlying object was and test if it was a `ConcurrentHashMap` or not (major flaw in Scala in my opinion, since some function that runs a multi-threaded task cannot effectively prevent the the function caller from passing in a non-concurrent object).

But this at least provides an empirical way to test it.

**Acknowledgments**

A similar question was asked in [How can I test that ConcurrentHashMap is truly thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567495/how-can-i-test-that-concurrenthashmap-is-truley-thread-safe) . I've modified it to work with Sets:

**Recommendation**

I would recommend using a `concurrent.Map[T, Unit]` rather than `mutable.Set[T]`. The reason is that you will be able to leverage the type system to ensure, with 100% confidence, that the object your function/class operates on is actually concurrent.

Yes, you will lose the Set semantics, such as the `.add(setMember)` method. But you will gain safety.

If you insist on using a concurrent `mutable.Set`, consider making a wrapper class container so that you can prevent accidental initialization to a non-concurrent `mutable.Set`.

Comment: An empirical test is not a proof. A non-concurrent collection is not guaranteed to exhibit a particular behavior when being wrongly used by different threads. It may even exhibit the same behavior as a concurrent collection for an unspecific amount of time. In the end, you’re wasting a lot of time for a meaningless result.

Comment: Agreed, it's not a proof @Holger . I am using inductive reasoning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_reasoning . But without any way to "prove" it deductively in Scala, I need to use what I have on hand (which is some code that reproduces the issue with very high probability in my tests). To be clear, this code is intended to be run in an automated testing environment, where every commit will run this code. Chances are very high that a regression would be found within a couple of commits.

Comment: I think, it would be beneficial if you write something about the actual use case and the limitations of the solution into the answer.